# Mocking dependencies and code coverage tool shows not executed code

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, jmockit

i'm trying to test my bean as a component itself. So that the method i want to test gets executed correctly. Therefore i'm mocking it's dependencies with JMockit. I wrote two tests, one for validating the if condition to true, so the method ends immediately and returns null.The second one for executing the code below this condition also resulting in returning null. But my code coverage tool (JaCoCo) just shows that the if condition is executed and not the code below. 
Session is a field in the super class `ÀbstractBean`. The method `isLoggedIn()` invokes `session.isLoggedIn()` and is defined in `AbstractBean`.

**TrendBean**

```
@Named(value = "trendBean")
@ViewScoped
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class TrendBean extends AbstractBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -310401000218411384L;

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TrendBean.class);

private ChartPoint point;

private List<ChartPoint> points;

@Inject
private ITrendManager manager;


public String addChartPoint() {
    if (!isLoggedIn()) {
        return null; //only this block is executed
    }
    assertNotNull(point);
    final User user = getSession().getUser();
    manager.addPointToUser(user, point);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
            null,
            new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                    getTranslation("pointAdded"), ""));
    init();
    return null;

    }
}
```

**TrendBeanTest**

```
public class TrendBeanTest {

@Tested
TrendBean trendBean;
@Injectable
LoginBean loginBean;
@Injectable
Session session;
@Injectable
ITrendManager manager;
@Injectable
IUserManager userManager;

@Test
public void testAddChartPoint() {

    new NonStrictExpectations() {

        {
            session.isLoggedIn();
            result = true;
            session.getUser();
            result = (User) any;
            manager.addPointToUser((User) any, (ChartPoint) any);
        };
    };

    Deencapsulation.setField(trendBean, "point", new ChartPoint());

    assertEquals(null, trendBean.addChartPoint());

}

@Test
public void testAddChartPointNotLoggedIn() {

    new Expectations() {
        {
            manager.addPointToUser((User) any, (ChartPoint) any);
            times = 0;
        };
    };

    Session s = new Session();
    s.setUser(null);

    Deencapsulation.setField(trendBean, "session", s);

    assertEquals(null, trendBean.addChartPoint());

    }
}
```

**AbstractBean**

```
public abstract class AbstractBean {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AbstractBean.class);

@Inject
private Session session;

public boolean isLoggedIn() {
    return session.isLoggedIn();
}
}
```

Comment: Where is the code `isLoggedIn` ?

Comment: added code for `isLoggedIn()`

Comment: I am not familiar with JMockit. How do you ensure that `session.isLoggedIn()` returns true?

Comment: hey arkadiy check my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having familiar problems the statement

```
session.isLoggedIn();
result = true;
```

in Expectations Block was the answer. Although i'm facing new problems, i'm going to ask a new question.